# Matlab: Could I change the size of the figures when generating a report?

Tags: matlab, report, figure

My figure has a lot of details. I found when generating a report, Matlab reduced the size of my figure. In the PDF, I needed to zoom to 200% to see the details of my figure clearly. I wanted to change the size of my figure when generating my report, but I couldn't find the option in the GUI. How should I do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the export_fig file on file exchange (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig). This allows you to produce high resolution figures. For example, assuming that the figure you want to save is the current figure (gcf) then you could save it as follows:

```
export_fig fileName -pdf -m2
```

Where -m2 indicates magnification factor.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I had trouble using export_fig. There were always some broken while lines, or white patches, or sometimes it looked like my figure was torn up and badly stitched together. I used -a1, but it did not help.

Comment: Werid, I've never seen these problems before so I can't help you with those.

Answer (score 0):

See the mathworks discussion about [saving a figure at a specific size](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/save-figure-at-specific-size-and-resolution.html). For example, you can print a bar graph to a whole pdf page:

```
bar([1 10 7 8 2 2 9 3 6])
print('-fillpage','FillPageFigure','-dpdf')
```